# How can a male athlete accept gold medals at competitions?

Tags: halal-haram, men, gold

I am thinking of taking part in some athletic contests. The authority will award the winners with gold medals. But as far as I know men aren't allowed to wear gold.
 
So how can one accept gold medals in a halaal way without disrespecting anyone? 
Please help me my brothers.

Answer (score 5):

The thing that you mention about Gold is to WEARING it. Wearing refer to clothes ,jewels and any thing that you use the verb WEAR for it.
Having a gold pen, a golden-ed phone or any other examples such this is not according to HARAM. what I've to mention is that it's not mater it is pure gold, for example a silver ring that is golden-ed in the surface is HARAM too.
Then having a Gold medal is not referred to Wearing it and is not HARAM.

Answer (score 4):

Dear brother the [medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_medal) is a symbol of recognition for sporting (in your case) achievements and at least you should know that gold medals are [not made of 100 % gold](http://chemistry.about.com/od/metalsalloys/f/what_are_olympic_medals_made_of.htm).

And don't forget that our Messenger used to accept gifts and this is a kind of gift!

From this perspective i can't see much harm in accepting it as it will end at a wall or a showcase (I even know some athletes who sold their medals because they lack of money!). And the athlete will not wear it as it isn't a kind of cloth or jewelry, as wearing it (as a jewelry) would be haram and as i mentioned there's a big difference between what you said and this!

Nevertheless scholars have mentioned several reasons for regarding even this as haram:

1. The hadith prohibiting the wearing of silk and gold for men as you mentioned:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) took some silk in his right hand and some gold in his left hand, then he said: `These two are forbidden for the males of my ummah.” (See for example in [Musnad Ahmad](https://sunnah.com/ahmad:935) and the Sunan books)

Further also the hadith on a men wearing a golden ring from [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2090) was mentioned.
2. Seeking similitude with women:

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) cursed those men who are in the similitude (assume the manners) of women and those women who are in the similitude (assume the manners) of men.  ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5885) and similar ahadith elseehere)

3. The last ahadith also was considered as an evidence for the prohibition to wear something on (around) the neck.

Note that the mentioned fatwas nowhere discussed whether the medals themselves in fact are not 100% of gold, but toke the attribution seemingly as given.

But there's a difference of opinion if the thing you are wearing isn't of gold itself, but in gold colors or colored with gold: So as for gold-plated things, it is established by many of the fuqaha' that if the paint gathers gold, when it is rubbed or put on fire, then it is forbidden. But if it is just a colour, and nothing of it is combined, then there is nothing wrong with wearing it.
Nevertheless it is regarded as safer to avoid wearing any of these because people may think it is real gold.

See also these wo fatwas in Arabic:

- islamweb #[63995](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/63995/%D9%84%D8%A7-%D9%8A%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%B2-%D9%84%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%84-%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B0%D9%87%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D8%A3%D9%88-%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%82%D9%87%D8%A7)
- islamqa #[122355](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/122355/%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%85-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%84-%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%A9-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%B9%D9%86%D9%82%D9%87-%D9%88%D9%84%D9%88-%D9%85%D9%86-%D9%81%D8%B6%D8%A9)

And Allah knows best